# When I try to use to redirect to another screen through master page this error happening

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When I click on link from master page I got this issue .How can I fix this issue

```
</a><a href="vacations.aspx">
<div class='<%= vacDetailMenu %>' style="cursor: pointer;">
   Vacation History
</div>
```

This is the code which I used.

This is the issue:

> "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length"

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your more code .. .
this is a error which comes when you put string length more than Real length,

```
  string muString="Hello";
  string substring = myString.Substring(0, 6);
```

and

```
   </a><a href="vacations.aspx">
```

is not Proper Anchor Link , You should use it like

```
       <a href="vacations.aspx">SomeText</a>
```